# React Native: How do I send a value from a promise returned by taskmanager to a redux store?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I am trying to send a value to the redux store from taskmanager in react native expo. I am unsure where I am going wrong and how to properly extract the value and send it to the my redux store. In my case I am attempting to access the `state` value from expo's taskmanager geofence api where state 1 means you've entered and state 2 means you've exited:

```
You've entered region: Object {
  "identifier": "court",
  "latitude": 40.7634642,
  "longitude": -73.9290698,
  "radius": 20,
  "state": 1,
}
```

How do I alter my taskmanager script in order to access this value?

```
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
    //this.props.setEnterRegion({ inRegion: region.identifier })
     ****** HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO SEND THE VALUE TO MY STORE
  } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
     ****** HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO SEND THE VALUE TO MY STORE
  }
});
```

Below is my other code for reference:

**Home.js**

```
//links for support


//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199774/expo-location-geofencing-not-working-on-standalone-devices-ios
//https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NUUN0dX4kE
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133892/expo-startgeofencingasync-not-starting



import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


class Home extends Component {

state= {
  inRegion:null,
  hasLocationPermission: null,
  myLocation: {
    //latitude: 40.6,
    //longitude: -73.5
    latitude: 40.7634642,
    longitude: -73.9290698
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getLocationsPermissions();
  this.startBackgroundUpdate();
  this.startGeofence();

}


//ask for location permissions 
getLocationsPermissions = async () => {
  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
  //status && console.log('location: ', status)
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
    });
    } else {
      this.setState({ hasLocationPermission : status })
    }
}

//define and start geofence
startGeofence = async () => {
  console.log('starting geofencing test ...')
  let x = Location.startGeofencingAsync('TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE',
    [
    {
      identifier: 'court',
      latitude: this.state.myLocation.latitude,
      longitude: this.state.myLocation.longitude,
      radius: 20,
      notifyOnEnter: true,
      notifyOnExit: true,
     }
     ]
    )//.then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => {console.log(res)})
    this.sendTask(x)
    //this.props.setEnterRegion(inRegion);
  
};

//start tracking in background
startBackgroundUpdate = () => {
  Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION, { accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest })
}

//send to store from task
sendTask = (x) => {
  console.log('entered region...', x)
  
  //this.props.setEnterRegion(x)
  //this.setState({inRegion : x})
  
}


  render() {

    //this.props.reducer.inRegion && console.log('hello:', this.props.reducer.inRegion)
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop :100}}>
        <Text>geofence test</Text>

      {/**
       * <Button 
          onPress={this._startLocationTrack}
          title="TRACK ME"
        />
       */}
        
        
        <Text>{this.props.reducer.inRegion ? `YOU ARE AT THE VOLLEYBALL COURT` : `YOU ARE NOT AT THE VOLLEYBAL COURT`}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    
  const { reducer } = state
  return { reducer }
};

const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setEnterRegion: (y) => dispatch({ type: "SET_ENTER_REGION", value: y})
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Home);


//DEFINE TASKS
const TASK_FETCH_LOCATION = 'TASK_FETCH_LOCATION';
const TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE = 'TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE';

// 1 define the task passing its name and a callback that will be called whenever the location changes
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION, async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  const [location] = locations;
  try {
      console.log('tracking in background...',location);
     } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

// 2 start the task
Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION, {
  accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
  distanceInterval: 1, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
  deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
  // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
  foregroundService: {
    notificationTitle: 'Using your location',
    notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and switch something off.',
  },
});

// 3 Define geofencing task
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
    //this.props.setEnterRegion({ inRegion: region.identifier })
    const final  = region
    return final
  } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
    const final  = region
    return final
  }
});

// 4 when you're done, stop it
Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION).then((value) => {
  if (value) {
    Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION);
  }
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    hasLocationPermission: null,
    inRegion: null,
    myLocation: {latitude: 40.7634642, longitude: -73.9290698}
};

const ourReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    const newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
        
                    case "SET_ENTER_REGION":
                      return{
                        ...state,
                        inRegion: action.value
                      }
                    break;
  
  }
  return newState;
};


export default combineReducers({
  reducer: ourReducer,
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
import Home from './Home';
const store = createStore(ourReducer);

export default class App extends Component {

  render(){

    return (
      <Provider store={ store }>
        <Home/>
      </Provider>
    );
  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your TaskManager.defineTask logic into a separate JS file and initialize it on your componentDidMount and provide your action creator to it so that you can make sure it has access to your redux action and run in a redux scope properly.

```
// Home.js

import { configureBgTasks } from './bg';

componentDidMount() {
   const {setEnterRegion} = this.props;
   configureBgTasks({ setEnterRegion });
}


// bg.js

export const configureBgTasks = ({ setEnterRegion }) => {
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_FETCH_LOCATION, async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  const [location] = locations;
  try {
      console.log('tracking in background...',location);
     } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});



// 3 Define geofencing task
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
         setEnterRegion();
    const final  = region
    return final
  } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
    const final  = region
    return final
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, it has certainly helped me set up my project properly. I am wondering, can I pass my redux state to the child component `bg` file? I'd like to be able to access values from my reducer in the functions within the `bg` file. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

After following this post, [Adding background tasks to your Expo managed React Native app with BackgroundFetch](https://align2source.medium.com/adding-timers-to-your-expo-managed-react-native-app-with-backgroundfetch-351dab97b96b) I managed to get a zustand state function inside the task executor, then just called my setupNotificationsBackgroundTask inside App.tsx function component and it works.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import usePersistAppContextStore from '../stores/usePersistAppContextStore';

let addNotificationFn = () => {
  console.log('addNotification not yet initialized');
};

const BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK = 'BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK';
TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK, ({ data, error, executionInfo }) => {
  console.log('Received a notification in the background!', Platform.OS, data);
  addNotificationFn(data);
});

export default function setupNotificationsBackgroundTask() {
  const { addNotification } = usePersistAppContextStore(({ addNotification }) => ({
    addNotification,
  }));

  addNotificationFn = addNotification;

  useEffect(() => {
    registerBackgroundTask()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(() => null);
  }, []);
}

async function registerBackgroundTask() {
  try {
    await Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```